# Как рисовать линии в JFrame?

Tags: java

Имеется автоматически сгенерированная форма JFrame в NetBeans с размещенной на ней с помощью графического редактора кнопкой. Как рисовать линии на форме? Я разместил на форме компонент JPanel и пытаюсь нарисовать на нем:

```
package graphic2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class DrawingComponent extends JPanel {

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gh) {       
 Graphics2D drp = (Graphics2D)gh;
 drp.drawLine(20, 340, 20, 20);
 drp.drawLine(20, 340, 460, 340);

}
}

public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Frame
 */



public Frame() {
    super("График по точкам");
    initComponents();

    jPanel1.add(new DrawingComponent (), BorderLayout.CENTER);  


}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    canvas1 = new java.awt.Canvas();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 202, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 156, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(66, 66, 66)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(175, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(canvas1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(57, 57, 57))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(65, 65, 65)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(9, 9, 9)
            .addComponent(canvas1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(39, 39, 39)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Frame().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private java.awt.Canvas canvas1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Но линии не выводятся. Подскажите как правильно выводить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой пример:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class LineHelp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(null) {
                        @Override
                        public void paint(Graphics g) {
                            super.paint(g);
                            g.drawLine(2, 2, 100, 100);
                        }
                    };
                    frame.add(panel);
                    frame.setSize(400, 400);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Необходимо переопределить метод paint.
Лучше учиться самому строить интерфейсы, без помощника, тогда они будут более понятны.